# innerHTML in ie6/ie7 bug?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, innerhtml

I user the innerHTML for the code:

```
<div>
   <span id="tag"></span>
</div>

var i = 15;
function timer(){
   var div = document.getElementById("tag");
   i--;
   setInterval(function(){
      div.innerHTML = i;// use innerHTML
      //div.removeChild(div.childNodes[0]);
      //div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
      i--;
   },15000);
}

timer();
```

the ff,safari,chrome is ok, but in ie8 value is no change;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for this kind of operations (reading/writing to elements)? That library is designed mainly to take away all the fuss with different browsers and browser versions.

Answer (score 1):

Following semicolon is 2 byte character.
try again after change to 1 byte character.

```
  div.innerHTML = i；// use innerHTML
```

Comment: i can't'understant this mean?